# ajaxForm formData get rid of newline in Textarea

Tags: jquery, ajaxform

I am using ajaxForm  to send my form.
I want clear my data of (newline) 
I want use .replace();

1-How can run a Replace to all formData of (beforeSubmit:)?
2-and what replace() option is good to "get ride of  newline of Textarea"?

Comment: Post the code showing what you tried.